# What should I do, it's hard to get PhD in any country but if i do an MBA in a country get a foothold after that apply,can I do that?

Tags: phd, masters

What should I do,  it's hard to get PhD in any country but if i do an MBA in France , what do you think can i get a foothold to easily get multiple PhD options in electronics with funding or scholarship

Comment: Hi Sandipan. Your question is out of the scope of this community, because it's too specific to your situation which makes it difficult to answer without being heavily opinion based. Questions here are also meant to help others in the future, if it's too personalized to your situation and answers are opinion based it is unlikely to apply to others. Could you please try to make it more focused and clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but an MBA isn't going to help you with a doctoral program in Electronics, nor with funding. The MBA is about management, not technology.

There are also two aspects of "hard" for a PhD. The first is to get accepted. The second is to actually complete the research required. For both of those you need an educational program that is relevant in some way to the field you want to study. For electronics or any technological field that implies things like math, computing, science, etc. not management.

In some places funding comes naturally with acceptance into a doctoral program, but it might be that the funding comes with certain duties, usually related to assisting in the teaching or the research of professors.  Again, and MBA isn't going to be relevant to any of that.

If you want to do a masters, and it is required in some places, do one focused on technology, especially the specific sort of technology you want to study.

See the various answers to this question: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)

---

Note that I've assumed that you mean a MBA (Masters of Business Administration) specifically. If you mean a masters more related to your field, such as computing or engineering, this answer will need modification.